# Como Traer informacion de otra tabla Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Tengo dos tablas , una donde estan las incidencias creadas y la fecha(tabla1), y otra donde esta las personas que estuvieron de turno en esas fechas(tabla2).

Tabla1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que busco es crear en mi tabla1 la columna llamada **persona crea** en la cual quiero traer al personal que estuvo de turno(de la tabla2) en esa fecha que se crea la incidencia. las tablas no tienen nada en comun para relacionarlas. hago este ejemplo sencillo porque mi data de powerbi tiene mucha informacion. espero me puedan ayudar, intenté con el **lookupvalue** pero esta funciona cuando las tablas tienen algo en comun, pero este no es el caso.

Answer (score 0):

para mi que si o sí tienes que tener algún campo que las relacione si no es imposible.
Para relacionar dos tablas al final tienes que hacer una tabla maestra con las personas.

Yo me haría una tabla de personas + idpersona y lo relacionaría con las tablas que tienes partir de ese campo idpersona.